# How to represent banking account information in a database?

Tags: database-design, internationalization, database-schema, banking

Hope this is not too off-topic. I'd like to know which fields are necessary to represent banking account details for customers that might be anywhere in the world.

I know about SWIFT (i.e. IBAN/BIC codes), but what if a customer wants to use the local account information (e.g. Germany: account number, bank code). Is there a "best practice" way to store this in a general form?

For example

- Account number (string)
- Bank code (string)
- Type (enum: SWIFT, US, Germany, ... ??)

Comment: Do you need to store local account numbers for international use? If international use, it'd be reasonable to require IBANs to be input and parse back.

Comment: @gbn: Well we'd like to support local numbers if possible (i.e. if that's not too complicated to implement here).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of today (Feb/2015) there is no agreed universal method by which bank account numbers can be addressed. The US has its own format ABA#/Bank A/C #, South Asia is different, Europe is different, etc. etc.

The original goal of IBAN was to provide some uniformity to this whole scenario, but I doubt we will be seeing that anytime soon.

Most companies who implement a global payout solution are well versed in the banking account information requirement of *each and every country*. Yes, as big enough of a monotonous task that sounds like, they have to do this.

tl;dr: there is no short-cut to this.